# How is maximum count for a Core Data relationship enforced?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I have a `User` entity that has a `to-many` relationship to `Location` entities. I have it set the relationship to be ordered with a `maxCount` of 50. When I create new `Location` entities and set them to users, does Core Data automatically delete the old entities. Do I have to check if the new size will be greater than `50` and manually delete the old `Location` entity so I don't have a dangling object that I don't need anymore. I have the delete rule set to `Cascade`.

The description of `NSRelationshipDescription.maxCount` is just `The maximum count of the receiver.` and I don't see anything describing how `minCount/maxCount` works.

Any insight to the behavior of this is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CoreData will not automatically delete anything, it will just fail to save the context if the current state is breaking the maxCount rule.

So it is up to you to decide what needs to be deleted and clean up before trying to save.